# Android App to compare between 2 XML Files

Tags: java, android, xml, rss

I know how to develop android application to pull one XML file and display it. 
But, I do not know how to pull 2 XML files at the same time and compare between the content.

Here are the steps that I have to do:

1 - Pull the XML files from the apple.com/RSS feed for both top 10 songs and top 10 albums

2. Compare both list.
3. Display only the Albums information on the screen which contain songs from the list in the top 10 songs.
4. Show the name of the album, name of the artist and name of the song.

Can any one guide me?
I tried to created inner class extending AsyncTask but executing 2 URL not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to execute **sequentially** (one by one) then you will have both the list to compare

or

you can have some **broadcast** concept to elaborate result once you got the results compare and define the final list

Comment: If you using sequence manner execute second URL in first URL asyntask on postexecute once second async on post execute finished you will have both the results

Comment: If you trying same async for both URLs simply you broadcast the result with key so once both keys arrived you can compare both.

Comment: I am using same asyntask for both but how can I broadcast the result ?

Comment: You know how to work with broadcast receiver . please see how to use broadcast receiver  http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_broadcast_receivers.htm